# Georeferencer could not create file

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to transform a tif file using GCP points and Georeferencer. First, there was a problem that QGIS gave the error `Error creating GDAL transformation`. Then I changed my points and made less points. The first error disappeared but there is another error that says `Error could not create file`.

Comment: Please add more detail, eg what QGIS version, what exactly you do, etc.

Comment: I often get that error and solve it by reopening transformation settings (the cogwheel). I think there's a bug

Comment: Best add a secreenshot showing your GCP points and your settings.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "Set Target Resolution" in the Transformation Setting and try to Start Georeference again.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the "Set Target Resolution worked for me.

Comment: Not a new answer.